# Xamrin - My android buttons look awful

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms

I'm doing what I thought would be fairly simple using cross platform.
I created some buttons and set the Image property to use some button images my co-worker created. In iOS, they look as expected:

[image: Buttons in iOS]

However in Android, there's a shadow border of sorts around every button and they seem to be set to some rectangular size that I'm not explicitly setting:

[image: Buttons in Android]

I've tried pretty much every property I could find on the xamarin button class and I'm having no luck. BorderWidth, BorderColor and BorderRadius don't appear to do anything. Can anyone tell me how to get rid of all the grey borders and size them properly?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Have you tried BackgroundColor = Color.Transparent, borderwidth, borderRadious = 0, BorderColor = Color.Transparent?

Comment: I have, no effect in Android.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you are seeing it the button itself, not the button *border*.

You could set the button color to transparent, but you will have a button border, and the width is unaffected as by default it will auto-expand based upon the layout container that it is within.

[image]

To override that behavoir, one option is to set the `LayoutOptions` of its `HorizontalOptions`, or you could embed the buttons into a grid, etc...

In the case of Xamarin icon which is 72 pixel wide:

```
new Button {
    Image = "icon.png",
    WidthRequest = 72,
    HeightRequest = 72,
    BackgroundColor  = Color.Transparent,
    HorizontalOptions = LayoutOptions.Start
}
```

[image]

Comment: Ok, I can size them to match the image size. Is there anyway to get rid of the gray shading "border-looking" thing?

Comment: @AS2012 The Form's Android `ButtonRender` is using an `AppCompatButton`, you would need to create a custom render, you can then set the elevation to 0

Comment: @AS2012 another option is to just use an `Image` instead of a `Button` and assign a Tap gesture to it.

Comment: WOW! Images with a gesture recognizer look perfect on both platforms! I don't have to mess with requesting sizes even. Thanks - even better solution I think.