# How to remove border from button in Xamarin 4.2

Tags: android, xamarin, xamarin.android, xamarin.forms

How to remove border from button in Xamarin 4.2

I have tried using BackgroundColor="Transparent" and BorderWidth="0".

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Xamrin - My android buttons look awful](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39648875/xamrin-my-android-buttons-look-awful)

Comment: Could you please provide an image of the button?

Comment: I tried BorderColor=Transparent and it's Works fine. Border Width=0 not.
Note: Using XAML.